# Buffer size in Java

Tags: java, file, io, buffer

I have got a little question about buffer size in Java. Why do we set buffer size to `1024` or `2^n`. For example:

```
    inputStream = file.getInputStream();
    File newFile = new File("C:/uploads/operators.xml");
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    int read = 0;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
```

How `outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);` works? Why do we use `bytes` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [read](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) bytes length of `bytes.length` from file stream and stores them in the byte array `bytes[]`. And then you [write](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29) bytes in outputStreem form `bytes[]` array. For more read the [Java I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) documentation.

Comment: But why `2^n`? Why not just `1000`?

Comment: @Tony Because [1024 bytes == 1 kilobyte](http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/why_1024_bytes).

Comment: So why do we use kilobyte?

Comment: @Tony Just for example.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid wasting hit to file system, byte sizes should be a multiple of file system sector size (e.g. 512 bytes).

Same applies to CPU L1 cache.
Most Intel 486 CPUs has 1K L1 cache, thus the value `1024`.
Pentium CPUs have at least 8K L1 cache, thus `8 * 1024` is also often used.

Recent file systems have a sector size of `4K` and recent CPUs have at least 64K L1 Cache, thus `64 * 1024` is also a choice.

Comment: This answers more of the question correctly. In reality, the file system doesn't read or write one byte at a time. It moves blocks of bytes at a time. 
I'm attempting to recall when I read about this awhile ago and so may be incorrect but I believe if you chose a buffer size of `508` and the system was moving `512` bytes at a time, the four bytes you tried to save would not be used by the file system anyway.